# closing browser window where angular application upon a button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser

I need to close the browser window where My angular application opened curently when a button is clicked in  UI.
I am using $window.close() on the button click 
but getting error "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it".
how to implement this in angularJS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Well ... the Error kind of says it all. You cannot close a window that you didn't open yourself.

Comment: What is the usecase? can you please post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: usecase is upon clicking a button from UI current browser window should be closed. I tried $window.close() and   self.close() options which are working fine in IE but not working in chrome